# Limesurvey resource manager opens save browse.php

Tags: php, survey, limesurvey

My limesurvey Server is doing strange things. After I uploaded a few pictures and deleted some the resource manger doesn't open any more. Instead Google chrome downloads an php file which contains the following. Anybody had the same problem or knows another stack where this question is more suitable?

```
<?php

  /** This file is part of KCFinder project
  *
  *      @desc Browser calling script
  *   @package KCFinder
  *   @version 2.51
  *    @author Pavel Tzonkov <pavelc@users.sourceforge.net>
  * @copyright 2010, 2011 KCFinder Project
  *   @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php GPLv2
  *   @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.php LGPLv2
  *      @link http://kcfinder.sunhater.com
  */

require "core/autoload.php";
$browser = new browser();
$browser->action();
?>
```

The bigger problem is that I'm only the admin user of the platform without physical access to the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a issue of LimeSurvey itself. I'd guess someone changed your server settings or placed a new `.htaccess` file which is causing this particular file to download instead of being executed.

You should contact your server administration and ask if they did any recent changes.

Comment: I will try, an let you know if was the problem.

Comment: They did some changes to the server, while updating from 1.92 to 2.0, so it wasn't a limesurvey fault.